# How to handle relative font-face links in css when using minified css files generated by w3 total cache plugin for wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, minify, w3-total-cache, relative-url

I have to fix some issues at a wordpress site which another developer has set up with a custom theme. The theme includes a `style.css` file which is referencing a font file in the same theme:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'foo';
    src: url('fonts/foo and bar.eot');
         url('fonts/foo and bar.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/foo and bar.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/foo and bar.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Without minification the style.css files gets loaded and fonts pointing to `<base-url>/wp-content/themes/<theme-name>/fonts`. When the *CSS minfy* feature is enabled the site fails to load the font files as the relative links are still the same and are now pointing to `<base-url>/wp-content/cache/minify/fonts` . The fonts folder does not exist in that location.

I've tried uploading the themes `fonts/` folder to `wp-content/cache/minify` which did not work long as either the font files got renamed to `.old` files or the whole folder got removed serverside. Don't know if this is the doing of *W3 Total Cache* or another process.

CDN support is not enabled. Configuration of the CSS minfy feature looks like this:

[image]

As I am pretty new to Wordpress I would appreciate any hint to a solution or approach I can look into.

I know I could try to embed the font files directly into the css file, but that approach is not wanted due to file size. So I am basically looking for the default way how to handle this with the **W3 Total Cache** extension.

**Note**: Replacing the relative urls with absolute urls is **not an option** as the site is used in different environments with sub directories and on main domain level.

**UPDATE** I have figured out that the issue seems to be a bug inside the plugin which is related to using files names including whitespaces. Have updated the reference code above. Version of *W3 Total Cache* is 0.9.6

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing exactly with the same problem, the version of W3 Total Cache I'm dealing with is 0.9.7 and I don't use whitespaces for the files name.

The only solution I have found is to use Font Awesome free CDN, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DmABxgPhJN5jlTwituIyzIUk6oqyzf3+XuP7q3VfcWA2unxgim7OSSZKKf0KSsnh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

You can include it in header.php. In this way, you will avoid any W3 Total Cache interference.